# converting observation to PDF

Tags: r

I have a question about generating PDF charts

suppose following data

```
x=c(1:100);
x=as.data.frame(matrix(x,ncol=5,nrow=20))
colnames(x)=c("patientID","feature1","feature2","feature3","feature4")`
```

I want to generate a PDF (portable document Format) for each patient that simply stats the different feature one in each line

```
patient ID : 1  
feature1 :  "give the corresponding value" 
feature2 :  "value of corresponding feature"
feature3 : "value of corresponding feature"
etc....
```

as if each patient is converted back to a clinical chart.

how would you do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. When you say "PDF" are you talking about a probability distribution function or Portable Document Format? If it's the latter, what exactly do you want the output to be? A single pdf per patient? A single _observation_? What would that look like?

Comment: sorry, for the confusion, I have updated the question (it's Portable document Format)

Comment: you still haven't told us what you want the output to look like, or how you would want it to work. From your description it sounds like you want a pdf that would be a single page with a single line of  text saying: "PatientID: 1 Feature :1 Value: 5". Is that really what you want?

Comment: ok, I will update again. (I want each patient to be on a separate pdf, and each Feature on a seperate ligne). in total. each file will have 5 lignes (each line containing a single feature and value of the feature)

Answer (score 0):

one of the solution I found is to first gererate a plot (then save it into a PDF format) for each of the patients.

```
x=c(1:100);
x=as.data.frame(matrix(x,ncol=5,nrow=20))
colnames(x)=c("patientID","feature1","feature2","feature3","feature4")

a=0.05
y=seq( 0,2, by=0.1)
y=sort(y,decreasing = T)
lapply(seq(1:20), function(i) {
  pdf(file=paste("Patient Num:", paste(x[i,1])))
  plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 2), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
  text(a, y[1],adj=c(0,0), paste("Patient ID",":",paste(x[i,1])),      cex = 1.2, col = "black")
  text(a, y[2],adj=c(0,0), paste("Feature1",":",paste(x[i,2])),      cex = 1.2, col = "black")
  text(a, y[3],adj=c(0,0), paste("Feature1",":",paste(x[i,3])),      cex = 1.2, col = "black")
  text(a, y[4],adj=c(0,0), paste("Feature1",":",paste(x[i,4])),      cex = 1.2, col = "black")
  text(a, y[5],adj=c(0,0), paste("Feature1",":",paste(x[i,5])),      cex = 1.2, col = "black")
  dev.off()
  })
```

It created 20 PDF files with the right formatting and the right info.